# Full page but contained background color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add a background color to the entire page by adding the CSS properties to body but I'm trying to contain the width so that it looks like a stripe down the center of the page but I'm having trouble containing the background color. I'm not sure if it's not possible or if I'm missing something.

```
.centerBG{
   height:100%;
   width: 70%;
   background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
   background-position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin:auto;
   z-index: -99;
}
```

I have here a CSS class that does the trick just like I want it except everything I write has to be within the container. I know I would have to do this within body{} but whenever I apply a background color to body, such as:

```
body{
   background-color: #000000;
}
```

Whether I add the width property or not, the entire background would be that color. I am currently using bootstrap 4 so if there's a way to do it using that library, that would be great.

Comment: can you share code or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
background:#000;
}
.background {
  position:absolute;
  left:30%;
  top:50vh;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: #58a;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(60deg, #FFF,#FFF 30px, transparent 0, transparent 60px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
</div>
```

Comment: set width="100%";

Comment: This makes the entire background black. The code that I posted does the same thing. I was trying to create a stripe down the middle of the entire page.

Comment: So, the problem is that you're using a class to set the background. In body, the background is still all black. In my question posted, class ="centerBG" does the same thing but the problem is that it affects other elements. The whole idea of putting the background in body is so that it does not affect other elements and acts purely as a background.